# How to apply themes into .zshrc file

Tags: themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

How to apply themes in a .zshrc file?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt.git "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt"

$ ln -s "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship-prompt/spaceship.zsh-theme" "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/spaceship.zsh-theme"
```

and then, I changed the text like

```
ZSH_THEME="spaceship"
```

then, I made .spaceship_config file and saved it (my home directory).

As manual, I put

```
source ~/.spaceship_config
```

this code into .zshrc file but it didn't work like

> source:12: no such file or directory: path blahblah

Comment: Perhaps you need to create `path` and/or `blahblah`?

Comment: I made .spaceship_config correctly and located in home directory, but it didn't work... sad

Comment: From the message you posted, I seems that `source` *does* find .spaceship_config. It just complains about line 12 in this file.